# Exception during hibernate saveupdate org.hibernate.TransientObjectException:

Tags: hibernate

Hi i have hibernate mapping like this 
    class name="com.example.Company"
        table="user">

```
<many-to-one 
            class="com.example.Organization" fetch="join"
            name="consumer" lazy="false" not-null="false">
            <column name="ORGANIZATION_ID" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one 
            class="com.example.Organization" fetch="join"
            name="supplier" lazy="false">
            <column name="ORGANIZATION" not-null="false"/>
        </many-to-one>
```

Before save update my database is something like this

company table

```
COMPANY   ORGANIZATION_ID ORGAIZATION
1             4            NULL

organization table

id   name
4     xxxx
```

now my problem is when I try to do saveorupdate org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.example.Organization.

I used cascade=all but every time when i save update it creates new row in organization table hence i removed cascade =all

when i was using casade =all it was working but it does something like this

```
company table
COMPANY   ORGANIZATION_ID ORGAIZATION
1             4            5
```

organization table

```
organizationid name
4               xxxx
5              nulll
```

it creates null. How can i solve this problem.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand from your post is that you are trying to add a supplier to an existing Company record. So you are creating a new Organization record, attaching it with existing Company record and calling saveOrUpdate(). So, when you don't set cascadeType=All, hibernate will of-course complain as you haven't yet saved the new Organization record in the database. When you do use cascadeType=All, hibernate saves the new Organization record in the database which in your case has an id=5, and then updates the existing Company record with this id. Hence, hibernate is functioning properly and doing everything you are ASKING it to do for you. Maybe you should elaborate on your problem and state what you exactly want to do, because whatever you have mentioned in your post is the expected behavior of hibernate.

Comment: Hi,

I dont want new organization to be created.

company table

COMPANY   ORGANIZATION_ID ORGAIZATION
1             4            null

organization table

organizationid name
4               xxxx

I want it to be like this after update

Thanks

Comment: So you have an exisiting organization i.e. organization#4 which you want to make a supplier of company#1 and therefore set company#1.organization = 4. Am I correct? (The # after the variables refer to the primary key in the tables, so company#1 refers to the record in the COMPANY table with primary key = 1)

Comment: company has 2 organizations.I am setting them in different context .In company table both organization_id and organization refer to organization table.when i try to save or update of compnay  i want it to remain same 4 and null in company table.I dont want new organization to be created

Comment: Company has 2 state active and deactive I am just trying to change state and update company .During this  changing state it created new organization.I dont want new organization to be  created

Comment: Clearly you are creating a new Organization instance when you are calling saveOrUpdate() on the company#1. What you should do is load organization#4, call company.setSupplier(organization#4) and then call session.merge(company). Posting some of your code can throw more light on what you are actually doing.